# Quickhull algorithm asymptotics

Tags: algorithm, geometry, asymptotic-complexity

I want to know, how fast Quickhull algorithm for many dimensions in worst case scenario (asymptotics that depend on dimensions size).

Can you help me with this?

And of course I was searching it, but don't find anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524344/complexity-of-the-quickhull-algorithm check this.

Comment: @ruhul thanks, I already check this and there is being considered **two or three** dimensional space

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found that complexity is O(n^[d/2]/[d/2]!). But article where I found this result from 1996.

Source (theorem 3.2): https://www.cise.ufl.edu/~ungor/courses/fall06/papers/QuickHull.pdf